# How to design worker to fetch from a data source concurrently without duplication?

Tags: concurrency, graphql, task-queue, system-design

I have a task like this:

- I need to fetch data from a GraphQL endpoint. The result is sorted by timestamp in ascending order, and for each fetch, I can query 1000 records.

Example for 1 record:

```
{
  timestamp: 12345678,
  value: 123
}
```

- In the next fetch, I will send the last timestamp of the fetched records along to start querying from that last timestamp. Each record's value will be summed up so that we have the latest total value after each fetch. Then this total value will be saved to a cache (for better performance when there are many queries)
- My boss told me to design the fetching worker that can run concurrently. Even if 5 workers run at the same time, no value is duplicated (to make data consistent)

And this is my idea:

- Use a queue
- The queue will only store 1 value at a moment: `the last processed timestamp`
- Any worker can start at any time and check if the queue has a timestamp, it will start from that timestamp
- Because there is only 1 timestamp in the queue at any moment, so there will be no duplicated value

**NOTE: what I want to achieve is a scalable solution, when multiple workers can run at the same time, but the data must be consistent**

This is my concerns about this idea:

- At the beginning, when the queue has no value and we spawn 3 workers at the same time (auto via k8s), all 3 workers will start fetching from the first timestamp => the total value of the first 1000 records is x3
- When the queue server is somehow stopped, all the workers will stop processing. If I implement it so that the worker can continue running, it will have the total value x3 as in the case above
- If 1 worker gets the last timestamp from the queue and it dies, the whole system will stop (because now in queue, there is no timestamp, and because the worker dies, it can't push the last timestamp into the queue)
- I don't know any queue solution that provides that kind of "1 value at a time". Do you know how can I do it, maybe in Redis or RabbitMQ?

So do you know how this kind of task is usually implemented? I love to read an article about this.

Thank you.

Comment: ***check if the queue has a timestamp, it will start from that timestamp*** Won't this be too slow? For each timestamp you retrieve you will check all the records in the queue until a match is found. BTW since this post includes GraphQL, can you add its tag?

Comment: Can't you use this pagination feature? https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/.

Comment: I've already used the pagination feature and have a working solution. But the problem is: it does not scale, when running 2 workers at the same time, the data will be duplicated.

By the way, the GraphQL node that I'm querying allows to skip 5000 records at maximum

Comment: Ohk, so you can basically run 5 workers each pulling 1000 records. Like worker1 - 0 to 1000, worker2 - 1001 to 2000, and so on?

Comment: yes, exactly. And if any worker dies, it does not affect the system

Comment: But why does data get duplicated if you pull the data like I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: when 2 workers run at the same time, they will just fetch records from 0 to 1000 (do the same work) => data will be duplicated. That's why my idea is to use a queue that store the last timestamp => only 1 worker can process data with that timestamp and then it pushed the last timestamp it queried into the queue